# How create ajax request manually?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need send request to action /Home/Start

Response set in element id 'js_script'.

I can not find how to do it.

Comment: Why do you mean by manually? from asp or from javascript? Also can you use a library like jQuery?

Comment: When I am faced with a problem in JavaScript, I don't "find" how to do it by looking online, I *work out* how to do it. Sadly, the vast majority of JS programmers are too lazy to do this and use jQuery instead.

Comment: @Kolink: One thing jQuery does nicely is cross-browser compatibility.  What if you figure out an issue, but it only works in Chrome, not Firefox?  Plus AJAX in Vanilla JavaScript is ugly :-P

Comment: @Kolink using jQuery for AJAX isn't lazy - it eliminates browser incompatibilities and adds very useful features such as "deferred objects".

Comment: @Kolink - I understand your position, and it's certainly the best way to learn a new skill, but many of us have deadlines to meet.

Comment: @ simply: Please leave childishness at home, it has no place on Stack Overflow. I've removed the whinge you added to the question. The reason people have been unable to help you with the question is that the question is unclear. Ask a clear question -- make an effort -- and you'll find a ***hugely*** helpful set of people here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a basic request then you can do it easily without any libraries with the functions find here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html

```
function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) {
    var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
    if (!req) return;
    var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
    req.open(method,url,true);
    req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    if (postData)
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
//          alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
            return;
        }
        callback(req);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
}

var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];

function createXMLHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
        }
        catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having to guess at what you mean, but basically, you use the [`XMLHttpRequest` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to do ajax requests. It's a Microsoft innovation that other browsers have adopted and which is now in the process of being standardized. It looks like this in modern browsers:

```
function sendRequest() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/Home/Start', false);
    request.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    request.send(null);

    function handleStateChange() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            // The request is complete; did it work?
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                // Yes, you can use the data on request.responseText
                // or (for requests with XML replies) request.responseXML

                // In our case, let's say we want to put all of the text
                // into the element with the `id` "js_script":
                var elm = document.getElementById("js_script");
                elm.innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's obviously quite simplified. On old browsers, you have to do a couple of checks around creating the object (`new XMLHttpRequest` doesn't work on IE7, for instance, but there are ways to do it on IE7.)

---

The complications around creating the object on older browsers are one of many, many reasons I recommend using any of the decent JavaScript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over browser differences for you, add a lot of utility functionality, and let you concentrate on getting your specific task done rather than worrying about (say) HTTP status codes. That's not to say there isn't a time and place for doing things without libraries — of course there is — just that normally, one can be more productive building on the work of others than going completely on your own.