# Using Ajax to flush obflush

Tags: php, ajax

Ok so I have created a wizard and everything works great. But I have one little piece that seems to 'bother' me if you will.

In the last step of the wizard I build, it uses obflush to process data onto the screen
to show some actions happening. But the problem with that is, that the 'entire' page doesn't load until the obflush process is done, and then the page all lines up nicely and such.

Im wondering if there is such a way that maybe ajax can flush the obflush process?

Maybe this is completely wrong but this is how I can envision it happening.

User goes thru the wizard and gets to the final page
The entire page loads
At the end of the page is some ajax code to apply to a  tag maybe
The ajax is refreshing itself every second to check against the update of the obflush and then outputting what the obflush has outputted to the screen.

Does that make sense?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Haven't really done anything to try it, it was a thought and I wanted to ask and maybe get some examples or input on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about how to load part of a web page with Ajax. In particular, how to load the structure of a page, and then fill in the details with Ajax calls.

I assume the intention is for the structure to be loaded quickly because it does actually have some content, and then load parts of the page that take a long time to process. Otherwise the effect on screen will be that loading is actually slower.

I would use the JavaScript library jQuery to help with this, although it can be done without any libraries as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354654/how-create-ajax-request-manually).

- The browser makes a web page request and the server responds like it would normally, but just with the structure of the page
- Within the basically empty page that was loaded, jQuery will then make an Ajax call with `load()` that will load the response from a URL into the specified HTML section.

The code would look like this, where `my-intro-div` is the id of a regular HTML `div` tag:

```
$(function() {
    var myIntroDiv = $('#my-intro-div');    

    myIntroDiv.load('/my_intro_div.php');
});
```

- The PHP script my_intro_div.php returns the HTML that is meant to be displayed inside the `my-intro-div` tag

There are some good examples in the jQuery documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

jQuery can help with a tonne of other things too. It has a tiny learning curve that can be a little steep, but after that I've found that it is the most intuitive "language" I work with.

Comment: so I am wondering if we cant get the page to entirely load up, and then lay a new layer on top of that page to begin to parse out the data. I tried the iframe trick but that doesn't work - it just returns all the obflush data back at once. Basically would like to have it "heres a page, heres the middle - NOW we load the obflush into that"

Comment: So you want to load the structure so to speak, get everything lined up properly, and the load the content in one or more "boxes"?

Comment: If that's the case, it'sAjax you need to look at. My favorite way of doing this is with jQuery, it makes it super easy to, for example, load some HTML into a div. check out this link: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: yes exactly, I want the page to load first and get set and then load up the obflush stuff after that. Because if not, like you said, the php is executed first (which does the obflush stuff) then it loads the rest of the theme - thus making it off center and all. Im trying to make it NOT happen like that, but the theme be loaded, centered, squared up, ready to go, THEN load up my obflush to process the data. Can you maybe show me an example? I'm sort of a newbie with ajax, but a fantastic coder.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this question. I hope it helps